# remove a tvos app from apple store sharing a bundle id with an ios app

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, tvos

I was wondering if it's possible to remove only the tvos application which shares a bundle id with ios version of the app. When I try to remove it, it seems I can remove both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible to remove the app/version from the tvOS store through App Store Connect.